# BeautifulSoup: Convert output to text

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

im creating a api to scrape a anime site to display a list of the genre, year, status, etc and converting that output to json format.
I can get the data but im unable to converte a list to text

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


#requests
url = 'https://www3.animeflv.net/browse?'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}
body = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

#bs 
soup = bs(body, 'html.parser')
elements = soup.find_all('main', class_='Main')

data = []

for element in elements:
    try:
        data.append({
            #1-- 'genre': element.select_one('select#genre_select').text,
            #2-- 'genre': element.select('select#genre_select').text,
            #3-- 'genre': element.select('select#genre_select option'),
            })
    except Exception:
        pass


print(data)
json_data=json.dumps(data)
print(json_data)
```

in the loop when i use the the number 1, the output is this

```
[{'genre': '\nAcciónArtes MarcialesAventurasCarrerasCiencia FicciónComediaDemenciaDemoniosDeportesDramaEcchiEscolaresEspacialFantasíaHaremHistoricoInfantilJoseiJuegosMagiaMechaMilitarMisterioMúsicaParodiaPolicíaPsicológicoRecuentos de la vidaRomanceSamuraiSeinenShoujoShounenSobrenaturalSuperpoderesSuspensoTerrorVampirosYaoiYuri '}]
```

Number 2 gives empty list and number 3 gives

```
[{'genre': [<option value="accion">Acción</option>, <option value="artes-marciales">Artes Marciales</option>, <option value="aventura">Aventuras</option>, <option value="carreras">Carreras</option>, <option value="ciencia-ficcion">Ciencia Ficción</option>, <option value="comedia">Comedia</option>, <option value="demencia">Demencia</option>, <option value="demonios">Demonios</option>, <option value="deportes">Deportes</option>, <option value="drama">Drama</option>, <option value="ecchi">Ecchi</option>, <option value="escolares">Escolares</option>, <option value="espacial">Espacial</option>, <option value="fantasia">Fantasía</option>, <option value="harem">Harem</option>, <option value="historico">Historico</option>, <option value="infantil">Infantil</option>, <option value="josei">Josei</option>, <option value="juegos">Juegos</option>, <option value="magia">Magia</option>, <option value="mecha">Mecha</option>, <option value="militar">Militar</option>, <option value="misterio">Misterio</option>, <option value="musica">Música</option>, <option value="parodia">Parodia</option>, <option value="policia">Policía</option>, <option value="psicologico">Psicológico</option>, <option value="recuentos-de-la-vida">Recuentos de la vida</option>, <option value="romance">Romance</option>, <option value="samurai">Samurai</option>, <option value="seinen">Seinen</option>, <option value="shoujo">Shoujo</option>, <option value="shounen">Shounen</option>, <option value="sobrenatural">Sobrenatural</option>, <option value="superpoderes">Superpoderes</option>, <option value="suspenso">Suspenso</option>, <option value="terror">Terror</option>, <option value="vampiros">Vampiros</option>, <option value="yaoi">Yaoi</option>, <option value="yuri">Yuri</option>]}]
```

I have tried in other ways but without succes. How can i get a clean text for the genre items in the list? The data output is not serializable with this methods
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `data.extend([e.text for e in element.select('select#genre_select option')])`

Comment: Bro, thank you so much, i dont even know what kind of magic is that hehehe. I need some time to understand that code but it work

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```py
data.extend(
    [e.text for e in element.select('select#genre_select option')]
    )
```

What it does is find all `option` tags within the `select#genre_select` tag and adds the text of each option to your list.